# Difference apply from vs apply plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Is there a difference except that:

`apply from:` - gets the (plugin).gradle from a URL

`apply plugin:` - gets the (plugin).gradle from the gradle plugin server

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### `apply from:`

- calls the script directly as if it was part of the build file

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins

### `apply plugin:`

- calls the Plugin.apply() interface

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:binary_plugins

Answer (score 36):

The actual difference between `apply from:` and `apply plugin:` is that the former is to be used for script plugins given a path to the local file system or a URL to a remote location, and the latter is used for binary plugins using the plugin id.

You can read more about it in Gradle documentation [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:using_plugins).

Comment: I don't think I get the explanation on the website. Are script plugins slower? Is there an article or a discussion that expands on it more than the documentation does?