# Task not found in root project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am confused by `gradle build lifecycle` for a few days. [Refer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) tells me

> A Gradle build has three distinct phases.
>
> - Initialization
> - Configuration
> - Execution

**Is task creation in the third step?** If so, how does `gradle` find all `tasks` in a project object?

Here is an example.

```
 rootporject
       |----app
            |----build.gradle
            |----checkstyle.gradle
```

The `build.gradle` is as simple as normal.`checkstyle.gradle` file has a task. Here is its content.

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type:Checkstyle) {
    description 'Runs Checkstyle inspection against girl sourcesets.'
    group = 'Code Quality'
    configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
    ignoreFailures = false
    showViolations true
    classpath = files()
    source 'src/main/java'
}
```

After `./gradlew -q tasks`, there is no task `checkstyle`.

**But if I remove the definition into `build.gradle`, I get it**.

Is there anything wrong?Thanks in advance.

## Edit

From [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html)

> There is a one-to-one relationship between a Project and a build.gradle file.

Comment: Does your `build.gradle` have an `apply from: 'checkstyle.gradle'` anywhere in it? How would the build script know about it?

Comment: You need to include your `checkstyle.gradle` file the way @mkobit described. Only `build.gradle` files are automatically interpret. Task creation takes place in the second step or, if plugins use the `afterEvaluate` handler, between the second and the third step. Tasks must exist, before the *execution phase* starts, but during *configuration phase* you may need to identify tasks via their name instead of their instance (`dependsOn 'myTask'` instead of `dependsOn myTask`).

Comment: @mkobit Thanks a lot, it works. Can you put your comment into answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't applied your other script.

In your `build.gradle` you should add an `apply from: 'checkstyle.gradle'`.

Comment: Here is a answer about difference between `apply from` and `apply plugin`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378249/difference-apply-from-vs-apply-plugin